# Hot to handle an overwrite error in lua due to "file in use"

Tags: error-handling, lua, overwrite

I'm running a simple chunk in lua copy function that overwrite a file:

```
function copyFile(old, new)
  local i = io.open(old, "r")
  local o = io.open(new, "w")
  if i then
    o:write(i:read("*a"))
    o:close()
    i:close()
  end       
end
```

Sometimes the "new" paths is "in use" and result in a VFS overwrite issue and prevent my code to run further.

How can I add an error handler that:
1. let the code go on if needed;
2. postpone copyFile function execution to let the "new" path to be no more in use

PS 
I'm not a professional programmer and I know only Lua.. i'm more like a modder.

Comment: What operation the error is raised at: `io.open`, `o:write` or `o:close`?

Comment: io.open in "w" mode, cause it says that is in use.

Comment: Use `pcall` to try to open file.  If attempt fails, try again later.

Comment: I'll check if pcall is available in that _G environment. Thanks!